# Table doesnt automatically populate items when selected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables; ItemType and Item. Item has a property named ItemTypeId which holds a value from ItemType Id. Very basic.

**ItemType**

```
public class ItemType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new HashSet<Item>();

    public enum ListTypes
    {
        Student = 1,
        Work = 2,
        Gamer = 3,
        Other = 4
    }
}
```

**Item**

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Graphic { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class TechDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TechDbContext(DbContextOptions<TechDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ItemType> ItemTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemType>().ToTable("ItemType");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Item");
    }
}
```

and finally the view component that selects the ItemType object

```
public class ItemListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private Data.TechDbContext _context;

    public ItemListViewComponent(Data.TechDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Models.ItemType.ListTypes type)
    {
        var single = await (from t in _context.ItemTypes where t.Id == (int)type select t).FirstAsync<Models.ItemType>();

        return View(single);
    }
}
```

Maybe I've misunderstood, but I thought when I used the correct naming convention the Items property would automatically be populated without any extra code?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Mark `DbSet` properties as `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Loading doesn't exist. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797

```
 _context.ItemTypes.Include(p => p.Items);
```